# javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected exception [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]; remaining name FactoryName

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a Spring JMS project managed with Maven. When I run the project via Eclipse everything goes well, but when I launch it from the executable jar file I got the following error :

```
INFO - Destroying singletons in
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@12911b4f:
defining beans
[jmsBridgeServer,messageFrameStreamReader,outgoingMessageEventListener,serverLifecycleEventListener,jmsQueueConnectionFactory,jndiTemplate,jmsQueueTemplate,jmsDestinationResolver,jmsSender,meridianMessageConverter,dataSource,transactionManager,sqlMapClient,messageInDao,messageOutDao,jparametrageDao,sequenceDao,deltaBankMessageService,parametrageService,org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer102#0,org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer102#1,deltaMessageListener,incomingMessageEventListener,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer#0,fglConnector,connectionFactory,rmiRegistry,exporter,attributeSource,assembler,namingStrategy,serverConnector];
root of factory hierarchy Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'outgoingMessageEventListener' defined in
class path resource [deltaMessageListenerContainer.xml]: Cannot
resolve reference to bean 'deltaBankMessageService' while setting bean
property 'deltaBankMessageService'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'deltaBankMessageService' defined in class
path resource [data-access.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
'jmsSender' while setting bean property 'jmsSender'; nested exception
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsSender' defined in class path resource
[jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
'jmsQueueTemplate' while setting bean property 'jmsTemplate102';
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueTemplate' defined in class path
resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' while setting bean property
'connectionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' defined in class
path resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected
exception [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException];
remaining name 'WMQConnectionFactory'   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:947)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:701)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.delta.jms.server.bootstrap.Startup.main(Startup.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'deltaBankMessageService' defined in
class path resource [data-access.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
bean 'jmsSender' while setting bean property 'jmsSender'; nested
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'jmsSender' defined in class path
resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
'jmsQueueTemplate' while setting bean property 'jmsTemplate102';
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueTemplate' defined in class path
resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' while setting bean property
'connectionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' defined in class
path resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected
exception [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException];
remaining name 'WMQConnectionFactory'   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 19 more Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsSender' defined in class path resource
[jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
'jmsQueueTemplate' while setting bean property 'jmsTemplate102';
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueTemplate' defined in class path
resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' while setting bean property
'connectionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' defined in class
path resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected
exception [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException];
remaining name 'WMQConnectionFactory'   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 32 more Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueTemplate' defined in class path
resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' while setting bean property
'connectionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' defined in class
path resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected
exception [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException];
remaining name 'WMQConnectionFactory'   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 45 more Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'jmsQueueConnectionFactory' defined in class
path resource [jmsConnectionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected
exception [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException];
remaining name 'WMQConnectionFactory'   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 58 more Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected
exception [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException];
remaining name 'WMQConnectionFactory'   at
com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.generateNamingException(FSContext.java:806)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:149)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)  at
javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)     at
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:88)
    at
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:153)
    at
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at
org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:200)
    at
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:186)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 68 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:170)
    at
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.setProviderFactory(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:167)
    at
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:271)
    at
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:72)
    at
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.getObjectInstance(MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.java:69)
    at
javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
    ... 80 more
```

---

Here it is the pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.disthub2</artifactId>
        <version>DH610-GOLD</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jndi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jndi</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jndi</groupId>
        <artifactId>fscontext</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jndi</groupId>
        <artifactId>providerutil</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>ibatis</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.726</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1B</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/config/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>datasource.xml</exclude>
                    <!-- <exclude>jmsConnectionFactory.xml</exclude> -->
                    <exclude>server.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>mq_setup.sql</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.delta.jms.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.delta.jms.server.bootstrap.Startup</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How are you running the java application on the command line? (exact command would be useful)

Comment: Thank you, Rob, for your help. I run it with "java -jar jarname.jar"

Comment: Ok, i suspect this is a classpath problem. Does your jarname.jar include all of the classes required for your JMS program AND includes the IBM MQ java classes that are included in your eclipse environment?

Comment: Thanks Rob,  I have edited my question above by adding the pom.xml dependencies.

Comment: could you please help?

Comment: Can you look at the manifest file inside the jar file and check that the Maven build has setup the classpath for the jar correctly. If it hasn't you can try running the jar differently to supply the entire classpath. for example `java -cp jarname.jar;<MQ jars>;<other jars> <name of main class>`

Comment: The MANIFEST.MF file inside the jar file contains only this: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: John
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: com.delta.jms.server.bootstrap.Startup
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver

Comment: Ok @Rob Parker, I will try running the jar differently to supply the entire classpath. I will keep you informed. Thanks

Comment: Hi Rob Parker, I did exactly what you said and I want to thank you for your help. I got a new error (I updated my question above). Many thanks.

Comment: I need help on  the same error, I'm trying to connect to IBM MQ using JMS/JNDI